# What is the derivative of a function in this form: $ \ e^{a x+b} \ $?

Tags: calculus

How do you find the derivative of a function of the form $ \ e^{a x+b} \ $ ?
Thanks!

Comment: You can treat it as $ \ e^{ax} \ \cdot \ e^b \ $ and apply the Chain Rule to the first factor; the second factor is just a "constant multiplier".

Answer (score 2):

Use the chain rule $(u(v))' = v'u'(v)$:

$$(e^{ax+b})' = (ax+b)'e^{ax+b} = ae^{ax+b}$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply the chain rule $\left(f(g(x))\right)'=g'(x)\cdot f'(g(x))$ with $g(x)=ax+b$ and $f(u)=e^u$. Therefore $g'(x)=a$ and $f'(u)=e^u$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = e^{ax+b}$. Taking the natural logarithm on both sides,
$$\ln(y) = (ax+b) \cdot \ln(e) = ax+b$$ Now using implicit differentiation,

$$\frac{1}{y}y' = a $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} e^{ax+b} = y' = a\cdot e^{ax+b}$$